# Where can I get a good Maltese grammar book?

Tags: verbs, reference-request

I am looking for a good Maltese grammar book which lists all verb forms, tenses, and declensions. Where can I find one (perhaps anywhere on the Island given that Amazon does not seem to carry such book). I have tried starting a Maltese language group on Stack Exchange but there was little interest.

Comment: Are you after a technical grammar (i.e. really only useful to linguists) or a pedagogical grammar, the kind a language learner would use?

Comment: A quick search turned up [this oldish looking pedagogical grammar](http://www.scribd.com/doc/84840533/Basic-Maltese-Grammar#scribd). I found some more technical works as well, but some are in Italian. I note that others have described the linguistic literature on Maltese as sparse.

Comment: I am looking for a pedagogical grammar. One in Italian will do as well. The link you posted is quite interesting.

Answer (score 3):

There is a book named: `BASIC MALTESE GRAMMAR` by `Grazio Falzon`.

*I don't know if I'm allowed to put the link here. The version I have doesn't seem to have any publication name or copyrght signs. maybe moderators can help me through this.*

Another book, freely available, is `TEACH YOURSELF MALTESE` A course of maltese for beginners:

> TEACH YOURSELF MALTESE. A COMPLETE COURSE FOR BEGINNERS. JOSEPH
>   AQUILINA. MALTESE, WRITTEN WITH A MODIFIED LATIN ALPHABET, IS AN
>   INTERESTING AND UNIQUE LANGUAGE WITH AN ARABIC MORPHOLOGY AND A VERY
>   MIXED VOCABULARY OF ARABIC AND LATIN WORDS, MOSTLY FROM ITALIAN. THE
>   COURSE IS PRESENTED IN FOUR PARTS, 1. ALPHABET AND PRONUNTIATION, 2.
>   GRAMMAR [ MORPHOLOGY], 3. THE MALTESE VERB, 4. KEY TO THE EXERCISES.
>   240 PAGES. DAVID MACKAY, USA, 1965.

Available [here](https://archive.org/details/TeachYourselfMalteseJosephAquilina) (From Archive.org)